# String literal should be on the LHS

Tags: java, string, equals, string-comparison

```
System.out.println("foo".equals(myString)?"Equal":"Not equal");
```

I understand placing the `String` literals on the left side properly deals with the `null` check. Is there any other performance factor with this or it is the "preferred" way of using `String` literals while comparison?

Answer (score 3):

That [Yoda condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) have no other benefits apart from avoiding a null pointer (That is also a debatable point. Not a clean advantage) . And it obviously kills readability of your code (*at least for me*).

Comment: If you don't need the null check I agree, but if it is yode condition vs null check + normal condition I think it is neither obvious nor oblivious what is more readable.

Comment: I strongly disagree with the statement that it kills readability. Also, he fact that it avoids null pointer exceptions is not debatable.

Comment: And for those kinds of cases, you should be using Java8's `Optional` anyway.

Comment: I assume we agree that needing a null check is a bad thing in the first place.

Comment: @Keppil Agree. May be not for you. I shouldn't generalise it. Edited.

Comment: another adventage of yoda conditions (not relevant for the question): in case the developer uses `=` to check equality it does not change the behavior of the program but results in a compiler error.

Comment: @FlorianGl Point is OP calling methods on a String literal. You are pointing out  `Assignment`

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ yeah, you're right, thought it was about yoda conditions in general.

Answer (score 1):

This is done only for avoiding the null pointer exception in case the other string is null.

Answer (score 0):

It's a more elegant way of comparing a string literal since it avoids having to make an explicit `null` check. There is no performance implication.

You ought to use it whenever appropriate. It signals to the reader of your code that you've considered `null`ness.

If you currently find it unreadable then put that down to inexperience.